# IBMWatson - How to run with cURL?

Tags: http, curl, ibm-watson

IBM Watson suggests some example on it's guide. But I can't work even a basic request.

```
curl -u "xxx@gmail.com":"password" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v2"
```

I can't understand why the request can't be authorized.

Error is here :

> { "code" : 401 , "error" : "Not Authorized" , "description" : "2017-11-24T17:52:58-05:00, Error ERCDPLTFRM-INVLDCHR occurred when accessing https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translator/api/v2, Tran-Id: gateway-dp01-1410026512 - " }

Answer (score 1):

The username and password you specify to create a service instance are specific to the service you are using.  They are *not* your IBM Cloud username and password.

See this link for more details:
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/language-translator/api/v2/#authentication

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more details. But it looks like your credentials are wrong, you have to use the ones that are in your application instance in IBM-Cloud.

Comment: What details? I create an IBM cloud account. Then, I try to run sample code in terminal with curl. IBMid is my email.

Comment: Here is a question about authorization failed. https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/207129/authorization-service-usage/

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your problem! You are using your the Email and Password that you are using to log in to IBM Cloud. Usually Watson services would have their own credentials that protect your Watson Instance.
To understand how to locate this credentials have a look here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson/getting-started-credentials.html#getting-credentials-manually
Basically this credentials will be written in the Credentials section in the overview page of the service.
I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using your account credentials, but cURL expects the service authorization credentials, to access these credentials
Log into your IBM Cloud -> Dashboard -> Select Service (In your case language translator) -> Go to Credentials -> if you have one use the username and password from here else create credentials and use those credentials.

FYI they are not your email id and password